# Jmeter Web driver sampler

Tags: browser-automation, performance, jmeter, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins

Jmeter has a webdriver sampler. We have to write the scripts. We have scripts written in opkey, a selenium based tool. Can we integrate both of them. So that we don't have to write scripts in jmeter.

Comment: see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874491/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/29878106#29878106

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what language is being used in opkey, JMeter's [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) currently supports only JavaScript via [JSR223 / Mozilla Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino)

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) to learn how to implement the most common activities in JavaScript. I believe that some refactoring will be still required, however using regex replacements if may be done relatively fast.

Comment: The webDriver sampler doesn't support chrome driver?

Comment: It does. http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/